# How can I simplify $\prod \limits_{l=1}^{a} \frac{1}{4^a} \cdot 16^l$?

Tags: linear-algebra, products

> How can I simplify $\prod \limits_{l=1}^{a} \frac{1}{4^a} \cdot 16^l$?

I've tried looking at the terms and finding something in there to conlcude what it might be and also took the $n^{th}$ term of $16^l$ into one fraction but that does rather the opposite of simplification.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$\prod_{l=1}^{a}\frac{16^l}{4^a} = \frac{1}{4^{a^2}}\prod_{l=1}^{a}16^l = 4^{-a^2} 16^{\sum_{l=1}^{a}l} = 4^{-a^2} 4^{a(a+1)}=\color{red}{4^a}.$$

Comment: Thanks, it looks beautiful!

Comment: An alternative approach is to exploit symmetry in the following way: $$\prod_{l=1}^{a}\frac{16^l}{4^a} = 4^a\prod_{l=0}^{a}\frac{16^l}{4^a} = 4^a\sqrt{\prod_{l=0}^{a}\frac{16^{a-l}16^l}{16^a}} = 4^a.$$

Answer (score 0):

Following Jack's answer and using $\sum_{k=1}^{n} k = n(n+1)/2$ it can be seen that:
\begin{align}
\prod_{k=1}^{n} \left\{ \frac{x^{2k}}{y^{n}} \right\} &= \left( y^{-n} \right)^{n} \, \left( \prod_{k=1}^{n} x^{2k} \right) \\
&= y^{-n^{2}} \, x^{2 \, \sum_{k=1}^{n} k } = y^{-n^{2}} \, x^{n^{2} + n } \\
&= x^{n} \, \left( \frac{x}{y}\right)^{n^{2}}.
\end{align}
Examples:

- $y=x$
  $$\prod_{k=1}^{n} \left\{ \frac{x^{2k}}{x^{n}} \right\} = x^{n}$$
- $y = x^{2}$
  $$\prod_{k=1}^{n} \left\{ \frac{x^{2k}}{x^{2n}} \right\} = \frac{1}{x^{n(n-1)}}$$